# Determine number of threads waiting in threadpool in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to see how many threads are waiting to execute in the queue of the Threadpool?

If I do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { TaskTest(); }));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Inside TaskTest, I do some work that typically takes ~500ms, I also update a variable with the highest number of threads seen:

```
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxthreads, out completionthreads);
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availablethreads, out completionthreads);

int threads_in_use = maxthreads - availablethreads;
mHighwaterThreads = Math.Max(mHighwaterThreads, threads_in_use);
```

Max threads, for my computer, is usually above 32000.  mHighwaterThreads is usually around 75.

I would like to know if there is a way to see how many threads are waiting to execute in the Threadpool.

Comment: do you mean how many tasks are waiting to run in the threadpool

Comment: If you need to know then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Hans, I have a server which, with each incoming request, creates a task.  Some of these tasks create sub tasks.  There are lots of components to the entire system and this was just another number I was hoping to view that could lead to any performance clues.  So no, I don't need to know, but it would be interesting.

Comment: @pm100 Yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: While debugging its possible to view this

Comment: @Sievajet Assuming you're talking about the Threads view, which I use frequently for smaller cases but was hoping for something programmatic to limit my interference.

Comment: Did you try WinDBG? It can inspect this sort of thing also

Comment: @Cuthbert no, he does not doing it wrong! We need to be able to observe health of a system : the number of threads of threadpool is auto-adjusted by .NET, but how do you know your code is working well or is about to die ? you can observe Threadpool queue length and it must not raise permanently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.pendingworkitemcount?view=netcore-3.1

Another possibility if you're running .net core, is to run `dotnet counters monitor --process-id 123`

This will give you a console display of some runtime metrics. I believe the metric you're asking about is 3rd from the bottom.

```
Press p to pause, r to resume, q to quit.
    Status: Running

[System.Runtime]
    % Time in GC since last GC (%)                         0
    Allocation Rate / 1 sec (B)                       66,480
    CPU Usage (%)                                          0
    Exception Count / 1 sec                                0
    GC Heap Size (MB)                                    234
    Gen 0 GC Count / 60 sec                                0
    Gen 0 Size (B)                               200,991,744
    Gen 1 GC Count / 60 sec                                0
    Gen 1 Size (B)                                   385,440
    Gen 2 GC Count / 60 sec                                0
    Gen 2 Size (B)                               210,807,272
    LOH Size (B)                                  74,140,000
    Monitor Lock Contention Count / 1 sec                  0
    Number of Active Timers                              314
    Number of Assemblies Loaded                          272
    ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count / 1 sec          38
    ThreadPool Queue Length                                0
    ThreadPool Thread Count                                9
    Working Set (MB)                                     242
```

Some useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn54CjePzs0

Comment: How could I see the queued threads in a dotnet framework application (since ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount is part of dotnet core)?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found a way to obtain the count of Tasks waiting for execution in ThreadPool.

But I found a way to **Monitor ThreadPool health**:

I create a single global Timer (let's say every 5 seconds) and I measure the delay from the previous "Elapsed": 
 as [Microsoft .NET Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) are executed in ThreadPool, if delay is abnormal, for example 7 seconds, I know the Elapsed has had to wait a lot, so the ThreadPool was saturated.

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple method to know how many Task.Run are awaiting ThreadPool execution, by incrementing a counter at the moment I call Task.Run and decrementing it at the moment the code really executes :

```
long waitingTaskCount = 0; // Current number of Tasks waiting for execution
long executedTasksCount = 0; // Total number of executed Tasks
long totalWaitingTimeMs = 0; // Total waiting time in ms

void ExecutingMethod()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingTaskCount);
    Stopwatch swTaskWaitingTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref waitingTaskCount);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref executedTasksCount); 
        Interlocked.Add(ref totalWaitingTimeMs ,swTaskWaitingTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;    
        // (...)
    };
}
```

And I also added a waiting time counter and a tasks execution count.

- So to obtain mean waiting time in milliseconds, just compute totalWaitingTimeMs / executedTasksCount
- You have the currently waiting tasks in waitingTaskCount